# C++\Win32 API - Difference between WC_BUTTON and "BUTTON" window classes

Tags: c++, winapi, button, manifest

Is there a difference or is it as simple as #define WC_BUTTON "BUTTON"? Also, if I use InitCommonControlsEx in place of InitCommonControls, do I still need to include a manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its as you say:

```
CommCtrl.h

// Button Class Name
#define WC_BUTTONA  "Button"
#define WC_BUTTONW  L"Button"
```

You still need a manifest if you use `InitCommonControlsEx` as you need to use V6 of the common controls.